# R creating timeseries with existing dates from file

Tags: r, time-series, rscript

I'm trying to create a time series plot using R where obtain the dates from a REST request and then I want to group and count the date occurrences on a one week interval. I followed the examples of ts() in R and tried plots, which worked great. But I couldn't find any examples that shows how to create date aggregation based on existing data. Can someone point me in the proper direction?

This is a sample of my parsed REST data:

REST Response  excerpt ....

```
"2014-01-16T14:51:50.000-0800"
"2014-01-14T15:42:55.000-0800"
"2014-01-13T17:29:08.000-0800"
"2014-01-13T16:19:31.000-0800"
"2013-12-16T16:56:39.000-0800"
"2014-02-28T08:11:54.000-0800"
"2014-02-28T08:11:28.000-0800"
"2014-02-28T08:07:02.000-0800"
"2014-02-28T08:06:36.000-0800"
....
```

Sincerely,
code B.

Comment: Can you be clearly on what exactly you're looking for? Desired output maybe? `aggregate(...)` is a good function for aggregating stuff, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the date with "as.Date" and then create a time series with "xts", as it allows merging by any period of time.

```
library(xts)
REST$date <- as.Date(REST$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
REST$variable <- seq(0,2.4,by=.3)

ts <- xts(REST[,"variable"], order.by=REST[,"date"])

> to.monthly(ts)
         ts.Open ts.High ts.Low ts.Close
Dec 2013     1.2     1.2    1.2      1.2
Xan 2014     0.6     0.9    0.0      0.0
Feb 2014     1.5     2.4    1.5      2.4

> to.weekly(ts)
            ts.Open ts.High ts.Low ts.Close
 2013-12-16     1.2     1.2    1.2      1.2
 2014-01-16     0.6     0.9    0.0      0.0
 2014-02-28     1.5     2.4    1.5      2.4
```

Not sure if this is what you needed. Is it?

Comment: Thanks! @galman this works like a charm. Does the library have any function that can sum all the values for the month/week?

Comment: See period.apply(), apply.weekly(), apply.monthly() and similar: apply.monthly(my_ts.ts, sum)